# Space marks in paragraph mode in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, whitespace

In paragraph mode in Word, a space is usually represented by a dot, in the centre of the line (like a `\cdot` in LaTeX).

However a Word file I received denotes them with dots at the bottom of the line (like a full stop / period `.`)  If I remove the space and type a new space, it shows the expected behaviour (centre of line).

I'm using Office 365.  The text is in Telugu, original text was typed on iOS and shared via Email.  I checked the Unicode characters by pressing Alt+X, it was 0020 in both cases (U+0020 SPACE).

[Screenshot of before and after opening paragraph mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ns5HJ.jpg)

[Example word file](https://1drv.ms/w/s!AnN4USuHBeLijmRIrAoAHI50GMgc?e=cKtw71)

Does anyone know what is going on?  The mark is quite confusing because of its similarity to a full stop!

Comment: You need to post the document, or at least a part of it, for us to analyze.

Comment: @harrymc Just added a part of the document, it has two types of space marks in Paragraph mode

Comment: It asks me to sign up... Please pick somewhere else, OneDrive, Dropbox or anything else.

Comment: Sorry, never used Scribd before.  Uploaded to OneDrive

Comment: Downloaded. I understand you have turned on "Show paragraph marks". Is this how it looks like on your computer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKX7h.jpg ? Because I can't see the effects you describe.

Comment: Yes - there are two types of spaces?  Looks like you have a different default font - the spaces are either a big central dot or a small one in your picture

Comment: The font used for me is called "Mangal". Is yours the same? Try also to use [Word in Safe Mode](https://www.howtogeek.com/322260/how-to-open-word-excel-or-powerpoint-in-safe-mode/).

Comment: I was using ‘Murty Telugu’ but it’s visible in Mangal too — see the last space on the third and fourth lines in your screenshot, compared to the rest.  If you add a new space, it behaves the same way

Answer (score 0):

I don't see space symbols that look like a full stop period, but I do see 2 symbols used for the spaces - a thick dot and a thin square.
The squares are a different font. On my computer most of your text is display in font called Mangal, but the spaces represented with a thin square are Calibri.

I'm guessing that your computer uses a different language than mine, so your fonts (and thus their symbols) might be different. Try selecting all the text and setting the font to your main font.

[image: Different font for spaces]

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with how Word treats text in different languages; I checked that the Language in the bottom left corner is English for one type of space and Telugu for the other.  Not able to get what exactly this means though.

Comment: I tried changing the whole text to one font but that did not work:  https://imgur.com/a/CLDqlmy.  Some fonts like Calibri (Body) and Mangal (Body) showed only one symbol but changing it back to Calibri Light (Headings) or Murty Telugu changed it back to how it was.  Find and replace space with space did not work either.

Comment: It was worth a try. Obviously there is something different about those characters, but it is difficult to figure out what it is. Probably not worth any more time...